# USGS/FGDC SVG geoscience point symbols for use in QGIS

Tags: qgis, svg, usgs, geology, inkscape

I have over 700 symbols created and tested for use on geological maps, using the USGS symbol documents as a source (https://ngmdb.usgs.gov/fgdc_gds/), converting the original PDF using Inkscape.

I am using only a few of these on my own geological maps, so wondered if they would be of more general interest or use in the QGIS community. They are at http://members.iinet.net.au/~richard.langford/USGS.zip, and if they are fit for purpose I would like to know.

Has anyone already done this for USGS symbols as SVGs, or is this new?

Comment: see [QGIS Geology Symbology FGDC Compliant Geology Symbology for QGIS](https://sourceforge.net/projects/qgisgeologysymbology/files/) :  "An implementation of many of the USGS FGDC Geological Map Symbolization for use by QGIS. Also included is a set of QGIS .qml files representing the geochronostratigraphic colour scheme proposed by the Commission for the Geological Map of the World'

Comment: Hi Stefan. Thanks for the heads up. I am sorry that I missed your post, so thanks for letting me know. I, foolishly, chose to do all 700+ symbols...everything from fossils to volcanoes. If you would like to add them to your project, please go ahead. Rich

Comment: I have searched using usgs, fgdc and "geology symbology", and your work does not appear. Why am I missing it?

Answer (score 1):

Using a QGIS plugin called [SLYR](https://plugins.qgis.org/planet/tag/slyr/) I was able to convert the current ESRI style file I use for FGDC symbols in Arc into an XML sheet. I have it located here: https://github.com/moendopi/QGIS-FGDC-Symbols-complete/tree/main

No need to mess with SVG's anymore as the tool built everything into the XML sheet.